# Using A Reference Range to Randomly Highlight Cells In Adjacent Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to highlight rows on a data table (Table 1), at random, based on two criteria from Table 2. I have spent hours searching for a solution to this problem but have not found it.

I have two tables of data. Table 1 contains two columns, Column A which will have a "Check" word coded to be populated automatically based on criteria in table 2, and Column B which has different names down the rows, some of which can be duplicated. (ex: Jane, Rich, Rick, Janna, Jane, Jane, Jane, etc.)

Table 2 Column A will have all the names de-duplicated from Table 1 Column B, and Table 2 Column B will have a number which indicates the number of rows to be highlighted in Table 1.

[Table 1 & Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Vtm.jpg)

I would like to write a code in which the number of rows in Table 2 Column B will be randomly selected in Table 1 based on the matching name from Table 2, and Table 1 Column A will automatically be populated with the word "Check" and highlight the entire row as well.

[Finished Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atXkj.jpg)

Thank you in advance for any guidance that can be given.

Comment: you'd better add data examples ("before" and "after" scenarios) and some code of yours, even if not functioning

Comment: Hi user3598756, I have attached "before' and "after" scenarios of my problem. In regards to the code, I do not know even where to start. I appreciate any guidance you can provide for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can use conditional formatting to highlight a column based upon another one. Or you could write a macro to change the colors.

Your description doesn't really explain properly what you are trying to do.

In order to choose your random rows you need some sort of event to fire. This could be a button, a mouseover, data entry, etc. Also when you say random do you mean you want to get a random no between the lowest row and the highest row and randomly highlight this. Or do you mean you want to randomly pick a name and highlight all occurrences of this name.

There are so many different variables and ways you could go about this that with the little information you have provided its unlikely anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: Hi ClintB, thank you for taking the time out to reply. Apologies for the confusion, please see my edits above. I have rewritten the question.

Comment: Hi ClintB, I have attached "before" and "after" images to my question. Please let me know if I can offer any supporting evidence to my problem. I am at a complete standstill on my automation project with this. Thank you.